# Run Python excutable ( compiled using pyinstaller ) in powershell and save the output in variable

Tags: python, powershell, pyinstaller

Run Python excutable ( compiled using pyinstaller ) in powershell and save the output in variable.
I have a python exe ( compiled using pyinstaller ) , and would like to save the output of main.exe in a powershell variable . How should i call it ? Just running main.exe and assigning a variable always comes as empty or null.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEhEp.png)

even the simple attached code is not working :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5GzH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At firts, go in your `.py` file and `import sys`
This module is in the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/), so you don't have to install it.

Then, at the end of the file, include `sys.stdout.write()`, passing it the value you want to save.

Recompile your program using pyinstaller.

Open the powershell, and move to the directory you saved the `main.exe` file

Launch `$VariableName = main`

- Edit after discussion

Do this:

```
def getpwdtoconnect():
   pwdtoconnect = getSecret('kevy', 'test')
   return pwdtoconnect

sys.stdout.write(getpwdtoconnect())
```

Comment: Tried this , but still no luck. I am also converting the single line output to a string , but still the output not getting saved in a variable nor getting printed ( in cmdline ) . But if i just run .py file , it works

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: import sys
from azhandler import getSecret

def getpwdtoconnect():
    pwdtoconnect = getSecret('keyv','test')
    #logging.info(pwdtoconnect)
    sys.stdout.write(pwdtoconnect)
    return pwdtoconnect

getpwdtoconnect()
#print(strOutput)
sys.stdout.write(getpwdtoconnect)

Comment: Ok, what's the type of `pwdtoconnect`?
P.s. For the next time, try to format your code :)

Comment: added the code snip in the main question.. pwdtoconnect is calling a function to retrieve few things.. it prints fine if the py is called... just does not work through exe.Also removed few code for confidentiality.. so ignore those red curls.

Comment: You forgot pharenteses in calling `pwdtoconnect`, now it should work.

Comment: Still no luck !

Comment: Added one more simple code to the main question , u can test - it does not work.               pyinstaller.exe .\main.py --noconsole --onefile

Comment: Issue was with --noconsole parameter in pyinstaller .  pyinstaller main.py --onefile

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with using noconsole parameter of pyinstaller. --noconsole should not be used if the output needs to be returned.